# Monodroid add map preview

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I am trying to add google map v2 in a fragment in a preview style but I am not sure how to fit the map with the desired zoom inside the view. When I try to add the the map in a full fragment it works correctly. I am using a framelayout and loading the map like this

```
  void InitMapFragment()
    {
        GoogleMapOptions mapOptions = new GoogleMapOptions()
            .InvokeMapType(GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal)
            .InvokeZoomControlsEnabled(true)
            .InvokeCompassEnabled(true);
        m_mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.NewInstance(mapOptions);

        Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.mapLayout, m_mapFragment, "map").Commit();
    }
```

Any ideas on how to add in a small prview format as in Sunrise app?
[image: Map location preview]

And here is the sample of how my layout file looks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@style/RegularMatchLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e5e5e5">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is your current result can you post a picture of it?

Answer (score 0):

I have made similar thing like this:
For layout I used fragment and not frame layout but it's the same more or less.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="208dp" />
```

Then I used this code to find the map and setup appropriate zoom level:

```
        _map = ((SupportMapFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map)).Map;
        _map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.ScrollGesturesEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.RotateGesturesEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.ZoomGesturesEnabled = false;
        _map.UiSettings.TiltGesturesEnabled = false;
        var location = new LatLng(_item.Latitude, _item.Longitude);
        _map.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(location, 16));
        var markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.SetPosition(location);
        markerOptions.InvokeIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.ic_map_marker));
        _map.AddMarker(markerOptions);
```